# Pentaho Integration with Java Application

Tags: java, etl, quarkus, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I'm having some trouble integration Pentaho with my Java application. I'm currently using Java 11, and Quarkus 3.X.

My goal is to create an API to trigger the Pentaho job to run. I have the kettle and transformation files.

My problem starts from the dependencies. I have included these in my pom.xml file:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>PentahoRepo</id>
        <name>Pentaho repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.orl.eng.hitachivantara.com/ui/native/pnt-mvn/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<!-- ... --->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle-core</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.0.0-343</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle-dbdialog</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.0.0-343</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle-engine</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.0.0-343</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle-ui-swt</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.0.0-343</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle5-log4j-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

However the build keeps failing, and complains about some Checksum validation failed error.

```
[WARNING] The metadata C:\Users\vyeung\.m2\repository\com\test\testing\parent\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\maven-metadata-PentahoRepo.xml is invalid: unexpected markup <!d (position: START_DOCUMENT seen <!d... @1:3) 
Downloading from PentahoRepo: https://repo.orl.eng.hitachivantara.com/ui/native/pnt-mvn/pentaho-kettle/kettle-core/9.4.0.0-343/kettle-core-9.4.0.0-343.pom
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <!doctype but is 20a2e85df9bb48f83b22a28ddb975325b96db3cd from PentahoRepo for https://repo.orl.eng.hitachivantara.com/ui/native/pnt-mvn/pentaho-kettle/kettle-core/9.4.0.0-343/kettle-core-9.4.0.0-343.pom
[WARNING] Could not validate integrity of download from https://repo.orl.eng.hitachivantara.com/ui/native/pnt-mvn/pentaho-kettle/kettle-core/9.4.0.0-343/kettle-core-9.4.0.0-343.pom
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ChecksumFailureException: Checksum validation failed, expected <!doctype but is 20a2e85df9bb48f83b22a28ddb975325b96db3cd
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ChecksumValidator.validateExternalChecksums (ChecksumValidator.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ChecksumValidator.validate (ChecksumValidator.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Anyone have experience or success with integrating Pentaho with their Java projects? Thanks!

Comment: Please post the actual and complete error message.

Comment: And have you tried to force maven to do a clean install, something like `mvn -U clean install`, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @HovercraftFullOfEels, I have updated the question, and yes I have done that too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the right environment has not been set for the maven as in the [pre-requisite](https://github.com/pentaho/maven-parent-poms/blob/master/maven-support-files/settings.xml). I have documented [the updated maven in this blog post](https://tech-spaghetti.com/2014/12/29/maven-dependencies-for-building-pentaho-di-kettle-plugins/#for-pentaho-kettle-version-8-0-0-or-higher) for Pentaho version 8 or higher. I hope this solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks Rishu, I will have a look at it, thanks a lot!